# MOV instruction modify pointer

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to asm and I'm asking myself these (simple) questions:
If I have an array in `esp`, and I write this:

```
mov ebx,[esp + 0x10]
mov edx,[esp + 0x10]
```

Will `edx` have the same value as `ebx`?

And concerning `lea` (I saw that there was a lot of subject there so it's just to check if I understood correctly ^^), if I do:

```
lea ebx, [esp + 0x8c]
and ebx, 0x4
```

The `and` affects the address of `ebx` or the value it points to?

And my last question (still about `lea`), if I do:

```
lea edx, [esp, 0x10]
movzx ecx, [edx-0x5]
```

The `mov` subtracts 5 from the address or again from the value to which `edx` points?

Comment: As for no 1: Not always. The value can be written to at any time inbetween.

Comment: Re “the address of `ebx`”, registers don’t have addresses. Did you mean “the address *in* `ebx`”?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes that's what I meant ^^ @prl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will edx have the same value as ebx?

Yes, as you move the same value into `edx` and `ebx`.

> The and affects the address of ebx or the value it points to?

The and will apply the AND operation to the address `esp + 0x8c`.

> The mov subtracts 5 from the address or again from the value to which edx points?

The addressing mode subtracts five from the number in `edx`, creating an address.  The byte or 2-byte chunk of memory at this location is a source operand for `movzx`, which loads and zero-extends it.  (You forgot to specify the source operand size, so this wouldn't actually assemble.)

`mov` just copies data without mutating it; you can think of the address math as happening first; addressing modes work the same for all instructions.  (With LEA as a special case that doesn't dereference the address.)

As an example for the last question:

```
uintptr_t edx = 0x10 + (uintptr_t)esp;
uint32_t ecx = *(uint8_t*)(edx-0x5);
```

Or as C code:

```
char* someChars=malloc(32);
//Fill someChars

uint8_t* edx = &someChars[0x10];
uint32_t ecx = edx[-5];       // ==someChars[11]
```

Comment: @dl11: The C examples in this answer had some bugs which I think I've fixed.  Most importantly, they weren't dereferencing the calculated pointer, so the equivalent asm would have been two LEA instructions, not LEA + MOVZX.  But also, in ISO C you can't add/subtract from a `void*`.  I assumed `movzx ecx,  byte [edx-0x5]` so I could use `uint8_t*` instead of `uintptr_t` to work around C scaling pointer math by the type size.  (asm *doesn't* to that)